# flutter firestore stream mapping to another stream

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `menus` collection on firestore and I want to perform a map operation on each document and return a new stream. So, instead of the `Stream<QuerySnapShop>`, I wanted `Stream<VendorMenuItem>`

```
  Stream<VendorMenuItem> getAllVendorMenuItems(String vendorId) async* {
    var collectionReference = fs.collection('restaurants').doc('$vendorId').collection("menus").snapshots();
    collectionReference.map((event) {
      print("mapping");

      event.docs.forEach((element) {
        return VendorMenuItem.fromMap(element.data());
      });
    });
  }
```

and I am calling it within a build method just to test my approach, and I got nothing printed on the console, here is how I called it

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var fs = Provider.of<FireStoreDatabaseRoute>(context);

    fs.getAllVendorMenuItems("ewP3B6XWNyqjM98GYYaq").listen((event) {
      print("printing  final result");
      print(event.name);
    });
```

Any clues? thank you

UPDATE:

I wasn't yielding anything, however the `yield` keyword didnt help

```
  Stream<VendorMenuItem> getAllVendorMenuItems(String vendorId) async* {
    var collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('restaurants').doc('$vendorId').collection("menus").snapshots();
    yield* collectionReference.map((event) => event.docs.map((e) => VendorMenuItem.fromMap(e.data())));
  }
```

Comment: You are not yielding any thing in the function. That is why you are not getting anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you transform stream using the method you use.

```
Stream<List<VendorMenuItem>> getAllVendorMenuItems(String vendorId) async* {
    var collectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Files').snapshots();
    yield* collectionReference.map(
      (event) => event.docs
          .map(
            (e) => VendorMenuItem.fromMap(e.data()),
          )
          .toList(), //Added to list to Match the type, other wise dart will throw an error something Like MappedList is not a sub type of List
    );
  }
```

This is a second way to achieve the same task using a stream controller.

```
  Stream<List<VendorMenuItem>> getAllVendorMenuItems2(String vendorId) {
    StreamController<List<VendorMenuItem>> controller =
        StreamController<List<VendorMenuItem>>();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Files").snapshots().listen((event) {
      controller.add(event.docs
              .map(
                (e) => VendorMenuItem.fromMap(e.data()),
              )
              .toList() //ToList To Match type with List
          );
    });

    return controller.stream;
  }
```

Comment: error: The type 'Stream<Stream<VendorMenuItem>>' implied by the 'yield' expression must be assignable to 'Stream<VendorMenuItem>'.dart(yield_of_invalid_type)

Comment: try using yield*

Comment: but this is not the proper way, let me update my answer.

Comment: hmm, that worked, but however the first approach failed?

Comment: First approach wasn't correct. Accept my answer if it worked.

Comment: sure, but can you explain WHY it didn't work?

Comment: First of all that way is not more readable or convenient. But the reason why it didn't work because you had an error because you are yielding a List<VendorMenuItem> in a Stream<VendorMenuItem>, You should change the Stream<VendorMenuItem> to Stream<List<VendorMenuItem>>; Let me Update my code.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason why it didn't work was I didnt realize the map function is only a middleware and therefore the `async*` is not required; here is an alternative to @Taha's solution

(without the use of a stream controller)

```
  Stream<List<VendorMenuItem>> getAllVendorMenuItems(String vendorId) {
    var snapshot = fs.collection('restaurants').doc(vendorId).collection('menus').snapshots();
    return snapshot.map<List<VendorMenuItem>>((event) {
      return event.docs.map((e) {
        return VendorMenuItem.fromMap(e.data());
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```